# Flatten nested spans in DOM using JavaScript to refine HTML editor output

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to use JavaScript to reformat input HTML so that the resulting output HTML is always a sequence of `<p>` nodes containing *only* one or more `<span>` nodes and each `<span>` node should contain *exactly one* `#text` node.

To provide an example, I'd like to convert HTML which looks like this:

```
<p style="color:red">This is line #1</p>
<p style="color:blue"><span style="color:yellow"><span style="color:red">This is</span> line #2</span></p>
<p style="color:blue"><span style="color:yellow"><span style="color:green">This is line #3</span></span>
<p style="color:blue"><span style="color:yellow">This is</span><span style="color:red">line #4</span></span></p>
```

To HTML which looks like this:

```
<p style="color:red"><span style="color:red">This is line #1</span></p>
<p style="color:red"><span style="color:red">This is</span><span style="color:yellow"> line #2</span></p>
<p style="color:green"><span style="color:red">This is line #3</span>
<p style="color:yellow"><span style="color:yellow">This is</span><span style="color:red">line #4</span></span></p>
```

---

Additional, somewhat tangential information:

- The text is within a TinyMCE editor. The HTML needs to conform to this pattern to make the application more usable and to provide a PDF output engine with usable HTML (`wkhtmltopdf` has line height issues if the HTMl gets too complex and nested spans cause editing in TinyMCE to be non-intuitive)
- jQuery is not available. Prototype.JS is available in the parent `window` but not directly in this document. I'm capable of reformatting jQuery code to pure JavaScript myself but can't actually use jQuery in this instance `:-(`
- Yes, I have existing code. The logic is clearly so horribly wrong that it's not worth sharing right now. I'm working to improve it right now and will share it if I can get it even reasonably close so it would be useful
- I really do know what I'm doing! I've just been staring at this code too long and so the proper algorithm to use is evading me right now...

---

Additional, halfway finished, nonfunctional code I am still playing with, to mitigate downvotes:

```
function reformatChildNodes(node) {
    var n,l,parent;
    if(node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'p') {
        // We are on a root <p> node, make that it has at least one child span node:
        if(!node.childNodes.length) {
            var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
            /* set style on newSpan here */
            node.appendChild(newSpan);
        }
        if(node.childNodes[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'span') {
            // First child of the <p> node is not a span, so wrap it in one:
            var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
            /* set style on newSpan here */
            newSpan.appendChild(node.childNodes[0]);
            node.appendChild(newSpan);
        }
        // Now repeat for each child node of the <p> and make sure they are all <span> nodes:
        for(n=0;n<node.childNodes.length;++n)
            reformatChildNodes(node.childNodes[n]);
    } else if(node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'span') {
        // We are on a <span> node, make that it has only a single #text node
        if(!node.childNodes.length) {
            // This span has no children! it should be removed...
        } else if(node.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'p') {
            // We have a <span> that's not a direct child of a <p>, so we need to reformat it:
            node.parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(node, parent);
        } else {
            for(n=0;n<node.childNodes.length;++n)
                reformatChildNodes(node.childNodes[n]);
        }
    } else if(node.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'div') {
        // This is justa  dirty hack for this example, my app calls reformatChildNodes on all nodes
        for(n=0;n<node.childNodes.length;++n)
            reformatChildNodes(node.childNodes[n]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would start by selecting all `span`s, then checking what their parent is. If it is also a `span`, check the innerHTML of the parent and outerHTML of the child. If it is equal, it's a nested redundant span. Then use innerHTML of child to replace innerHTML of parent. Not gonna do it for you, because you haven't tried anything yourself or haven't posted it. :)

Comment: If there is not span inside p, then just add it to it, this should be the easier part ;)

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I see I misread the question, sorry :D

Comment: Ok, I was almost there (or I thought I was), editing it on jsfiddle, then I made an infinite loop, has to force close the panel and lost the progress, I'm giving up and I should make more backups even when using jsfiddle :'(

Comment: Ug, thanks for trying @Jakub! I still have an older version of your code and was using it to reformat mine. It worked for some cases but not for others, but I think I am making slow progress.

Comment: This is actually a very nice excercice, I'm gonna try it again when I have more time just for pleasure :) if there is no answer by then, ill still post it :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution runs over the spans, unwrapping them (where necessary) and then continuing with the just unwrapped elements so that it handles all of them. Left are only top-level spans with text node children.

```
function wrap(text, color) {
   var span = document.createElement("span");
   span.style.color = color;
   span.appendChild(text);
   return span;
}
function format(p) {
    for (var cur = p.firstChild; cur != null; cur = next) {
        var next = cur.nextSibling;
        if (cur.nodeType == 3) {
            // top-level text nodes are wrapped in spans
            next = p.insertBefore(wrap(cur, p.style.color), next);
        } else {
            if (cur.childNodes.length == 1 && cur.firstChild.nodeType == 3)
               continue;
            // top-level spans are unwrapped…
            while (cur.firstChild) {
                if (cur.firstChild.nodeType == 1)
                    // with nested spans becoming unnested
                    p.insertBefore(cur.firstChild, next);
                else
                    // and child text nodes becoming wrapped again
                    p.insertBefore(wrap(cur.firstChild, cur.style.color), next);
            }
            // now empty span is removed
            next = cur.nextSibling;
            p.removeChild(cur);
        }
    }
    p.style.color = p.firstChild.style.color;
}
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/SKy4G/2/))

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to use `cur.childNodes.length` instead of `cur.children.length` which might be a TinyMCE thing. You deserve a bounty for this answer!

Comment: Oh, right. `.children` is the HTML-element-collection, and does not include the expected text node as `.childNodes` does.